# install rqt plugin with rosbuild

Tags: ros-fuerte, rqt, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently trying to write a plugin for rqt. But we are using fuerte in our project, which means that we can not use catkin. I followed the tutorial (sorry that I could not provide the link, but this program gave an error that I have not enough karma to post links) until the point were I need to install the plugin because it is not explained how to do this in rosbuild. Has anyone done that before and could tell me how to do this?

Cheers

Daniel Reuter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65679/install-rqt-plugin-with-rosbuild/) by [Daniel Robin Reuter](https://answers.ros.org/users/5205/daniel-robin-reuter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-06-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some search in the rqt_rviz package I finally was able to let rqt_gui detect my C++ plugin. I will try to describe what I needed to do (those things are only useful for c++ plugins) and what sometimes really confused me (correct me if I got something wrong, I will use the package name rqt_something and the classes name will be MyGUIClass):

- The package name (`rqt_something`) must also be the namespace (`rqt_something::MyGUIClass`)
- In the `plugin.xml` the very first line must be changed to `<library path="lib/librqt_something">`
- The second line does also differ from the example (because we are using c++)

`<class name="rqt_seneka/MyGUIClass" type="rqt_something::MyGUIClass" base_class_type="rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin">`

- You must add the following lines in the CMakeLists.txt before the rosbuild_add_library and after invoking the moc:

`rosbuild_include(pluginlib hide_plugin_symbols)`

`pluginlib_hide_plugin_symbols(rqt_something MyGUIClass)`

This should work with the example code from the
[C++ specific tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20C%2B%2B%20Plugin).
If you want to use a .ui file (in this case myguiclass_widget.ui) you should put in in the resource folder and add the following lines to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
qt_wrap_ui(ui_MyGUIClass ui_MyGUIClass_HDRS ui_MyGUIClass_SRCS resource/myguiclass_widget.ui)

include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

#Here comes the moc-part

#Add ${ui_MyGUIClass_HDRS} to the sources of the library as done in this example
rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${rqt_something_SRCS} ${rqt_something_MOCS} ${ui_MyGUIClass_HDRS})
```

I hope I did not forget anything. Maybe somebody could link to this question in the tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Robin Reuter](https://answers.ros.org/users/5205/daniel-robin-reuter/) with karma: 71 on 2013-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-06-24**:
@Daniel Robin Reuter I'm glad that you figured it out! I added a link [here](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin#Prerequisite_.26_assumption) to this QA thread. Also, please consider "upvote" other answers if they helped you ;)

**Comment by [goshawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18870/goshawk/) on 2014-07-15**:
What if we are using python plugins?

**Comment by [Daniel Robin Reuter](https://answers.ros.org/users/5205/daniel-robin-reuter/) on 2014-07-15**:
@goshawk if you are using python you should not have any problems. If you experience any problems don't hesitate on asking me :)

**Comment by [goshawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18870/goshawk/) on 2014-08-01**:
@Daniel Robin Reuter I made my rqt plugin using python & QT designer to build my .ui. The only problem is that I can't see the first instance of the plugin even though it shows it as running under the running tab. But when I launch another one I can see the plugin and I can close the first instance.

**Comment by [Daniel Robin Reuter](https://answers.ros.org/users/5205/daniel-robin-reuter/) on 2014-08-04**:
@goshawk Could you please open a new question and provide the console output?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can refer to many [rqt plugins in fuerte branch](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/tree/fuerte-devel) as examples (note all plugins reside in `rqt` `stack` - there weren't separate stack/`metapackage` for `rqt plugins` then). Except for `rqt_image_view` and `rqt_rviz` that are written in `C++`, all others are implemented in `python`.

Although I haven't tested, you probably don't even need to build your rqt plugins if they are written in python and not doing "special". In that case all you need is to export your plugins to `plugin loader` of `pluginlib` that's done by following:

- `export` tag in `manifest.xml` that refers to plugin.xml
- `plugin.xml`

The only difference between `catkin`ized `rqt plugin` and `rosbuild` one in terms of `rqt` is `CMakeLists.txt` (note that the general difference between rosbuilt and catkin packages is valid too). And the simplest `CMakeLists.txt` among those plugins looks like [this](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/blob/fuerte-devel/rqt_robot_steering/CMakeLists.txt):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
rosbuild_init()
```

You might be aware that `rqt` isn't fully available on `fuerte`, or at least the development and support is not active for it. So I'm sorry that the documentation will be unlikely done for `fuerte`. Ask further if anything is unclear but those examples should give much insight.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Robin Reuter](https://answers.ros.org/users/5205/daniel-robin-reuter/) on 2013-06-23**:
Thank you for your answer. I will search for the answer in the fuerte branch tomorrow. What I was worried about was the part were the plugin gets installed because it gets installed to paths defined in catkin. I was able to compile the plugin and got a static library but rqt_gui did not find it.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-06-23**:
@Daniel Robin Reuter you compiled your rqt plugin on fuerte by `rosmake` right?